# An explicit axiomatization of the universal theory of fields

Tags: model-theory

Is the $\forall$-theory of fields finitely axiomatizable? If so, what is an explicit axiomatization of it?

Comment: What is the $\forall$-theory of fields?

Comment: Do you mean the set of universal statements which are true of all fields?

Comment: @6005 I mean the set of universal statements true of all fields. Basically, the set of universal closures of boolean combinations of equations in the signature $(+,-,*,0,1)$

Comment: When you say "all fields", do you really mean **all** fields, or do you mean all infinite fields?

Comment: I mean all fields.

Comment: The fact that your language is (+,-,*,0,1) should be a part of your question. If you adjust the language your axiomatization may change: If $L=\{ + \}$, then groups are AE axiomatizable, where as in $L=\{ +,-,0 \}$ there is a universal axiomatization of groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: for any theory $T$ its universal consequences $T_{\forall}$ is precisely the theory of substructures of models of $T$. So to figure out what $\forall$-theory of fields is, you need to figure out which rings can be extended to fields.

Comment: Integral domains, got it.